# configuring django admin on elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I am having a hard time configuring django admin to work on elastic beanstalk. I  tried everything but it's still not working.
when I click on admin or my flag pages I get Server Error (500).
I have created a folder in my project called management in the root of my project, inside that I created another folder called commands and a file called createsu.py here is the content of the createsu.py
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Command(BaseCommand):

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    if not User.objects.filter(username="admin").exists():
        User.objects.create_superuser("admin", "admin@admin.com", "admin")
        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Successfully created new super user'))
```

in my .config file I added this like of code

03_createsu:
    command: "python manage.py createsu"
    leader_only: true

after eb deploy and refreshing elastic beanstalk console when I try to go to the webpage I still get the same error. all my other pages are working, static files are working fine except my admin and flag pages because they are connected to the admin. I have been struggling with this for a week now. can someone please help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#I fixed the issue.
#First typo was I forgot to add SITE_ID = 1 in my settings.py because I am using #flatpages.
#Second typo I didn't configure my static files correctly. I fixed it to this:

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)

#Lastly createsu.py should be in the app folder not project folder.
```